# Can't reposition picture in template to top edge of page

Tags: header-footer, diagrams, cv, resize

I'm using this template to create a CV and I can't move the picture that's on the right to be as I want. I want to move the picture to be closer to the top edge of the page. I tried all possible solutions that I know, but with no results.

This is the template I'm using. I turned the picture to be a square, but whatever I try it just doesn't move.

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/recreating-business-insiders-cv-of-marissa-mayer/gtqfpbwncfvp

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805).

Answer (score 1):

You can always move something by putting it in a `picture` environment. However in this case the placement of the photo is done deep inside `altacv.cls`. So you will have to change that.

Replace these lines:

```
  \appto{\altacv@right@photos}{%
    \@makeaphoto{\altacv@photo@diam@right}{#1}\hspace{1ex}%
  }%
```

with this:

```
  \appto{\altacv@right@photos}{%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
    \begin{picture}(\altacv@photo@diam@right,0)
    \put(1,1){\@makeaphoto{\altacv@photo@diam@right}{#1}\hspace{1ex}}%
  \end{picture}}%
```

The `(1,1)` are the amount of movement in centimeters (because I have set `\unitlength` to `1cm`). You can adapt this to your taste.

Comment: thanks a lot it worked out!